# Error: Property implementation must have its declaration in '<classname>' interface or one of its extensions

Tags: objective-c, swift

I have a Swift extension as follows:

```
@objc
protocol Themeable: class {
    @objc var themeGradient: Gradient { get set }
}
```

In Objc, I have some view controllers adopting that protocol, using `@synthesize` for the property.

```
#import "MyProject-Swift.h"

@interface MyObjcViewController () <Themeable>
@end;

@implementation MyObjcViewController
@synthesize themeGradient;
...
@end;
```

When building I'm getting this error in the `@synthesize` line:

> Error: Property implementation must have its declaration in interface
>   'MyObjcViewController' or one of its extensions

Is it possible to synthesize properties defined in Swift protocols?

Answer (score -1):

Well, this is a bit embarrassing. While working on this, I contemplated the idea of delaying this protocol in Objc, and I had this left over somewhere in the code:

```
@protocol Themeable
@end;
```

This declaration was on a header file, and was not triggering a "Redeclaration" error :(

Removing the above declaration made the `@synthesize` work as intended.